# Is fully-errata'd Hybrid Divine Challenge a No Action or an Immediate Action?

Tags: dnd-4e, paladin, errata, immediate-actions

According to the Essentials update 2 (November 2010), both the original Divine Challenge and the Hybrid Divine Challenge damage instance appear to have been errata-ed to be a no action event (yes, placing the mark is still a minor action). This distinction becomes significant when you hybrid a Paladin with a Fighter.

However, it seems that the Online Compendium was either a) not updated with the errata or b) stealth errata-ed to go back to an immediate action.

So who is right, in this case? The errata document or the online compendium?

Comment: Small nitpick, the last 4e errata was released in August 2012. Everything else you said is still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It was not updated with the errata

It is really hard to prove a negative, but the most recent official document (which insider is not) states that it was changed to *no action*.

So the Insider is wrong, and a hybrid Paladin|Fighter makes sense now.